# Wrong ROC curve for multiclass classification

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, roc, multiclass-classification

I have trained a CNN to classify images into 5 classes. But when I try to plot `ROC` curve for each class versus the rest, all 5 classes have almost a diagonal curve with `AUC` of around 0.5. I have no idea what has gone wrong.

The model should have an accuracy of around 86%.

Here is the code:

```
import os, shutil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers, optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, roc_auc_score, RocCurveDisplay
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
import random

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('G:/Myxoid lesion/Myxoid_EN3_finetune4b')

model.summary()

data_dir='G:/Myxoid lesion/Test/'

batch_size = 64
img_height = 300
img_width = 300

test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  seed = 123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

model.compile(optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00002),
              loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics = ['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])

correct =  np.array([], dtype='int32')

# Get the labels of test_ds
for x, y in test_ds:
    correct = np.concatenate([correct, y.numpy()])

# Get the prediction probabilities for each class for each test image
prediction_prob = tf.nn.softmax(model.predict(test_ds))

num_class = 5
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(num_class):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(correct, prediction_prob[:,i], pos_label=i)
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

plt.figure()
lw = 2
for i in range(num_class):
    plt.plot(fpr[i],tpr[i],
             color=(random.random(),random.random(),random.random()),
             label='{0} (AUC = {1:0.2f})'''.format(labels[i], roc_auc[i]))
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--', lw=lw)
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')

plt.title('ROC analysis')

plt.show()
```

The "prediction_prob" variable contains:

```
array([[6.3877934e-09, 6.3617526e-06, 5.5736535e-07, 4.9789862e-05,
        9.9994326e-01],
       [6.5260068e-08, 8.8882577e-03, 3.9350948e-06, 9.9110776e-01,
        4.0252076e-11],
       [2.7514220e-04, 2.9315910e-05, 1.6688553e-04, 9.9952865e-01,
        3.5938730e-10],
       ...,
       [1.1131389e-09, 9.8325908e-01, 3.4283744e-06, 1.6737511e-02,
        7.3243338e-12],
       [1.4697845e-08, 4.7125661e-05, 1.4077022e-03, 6.4052530e-02,
        9.3449265e-01],
       [9.9999940e-01, 1.3071107e-07, 4.3149896e-07, 4.7902233e-08,
        9.2861301e-09]], dtype=float32)>
```

While the "correct" variable contains the correct label for each test image:

```
array([0, 1, 4, ..., 4, 2, 4])
```

I think I follow what is mentioned on the `scikit-learn` website.

The tpr[i] and fpr[i] variables generated becomes linear correlated, so the AUC becomes 0.5

I think there is a problem in generating tpr[i] and fpr[i]? Could anyone figure out the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: the code should be ok.. just looking at your output for probabilities and true label, they don't tally, can you check with a confusion matrix?

Comment: It seems that model.predict will give a result with different order as original test_ds.

Comment: If I use
prediction = np.array([])
for x, y in test_ds:
 prediction = np.concatenate([prediction, tf.nn.softmax(model.predict(x))])
It will return:
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)

Comment: Is there a way to get the labels of test_ds?

I use:


for x, y in test_ds:
    correct = np.concatenate([correct, y.numpy()])

Comment: @StupidWolf The confusion is ok. As I generate the prediction and label as follows:  for x, y in test_ds:
 prediction = np.concatenate([prediction, np.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(model.predict(x)), axis=-1)])
 correct = np.concatenate([correct, y.numpy()])

Answer (score 0):

If I generate the labels and prediction in this way, then I can get the correct ROC curve:

```
prediction_prob = np.array([]).reshape(0,5)
correct =  np.array([], dtype='int32')

for x, y in test_ds:
    correct = np.concatenate([correct, y.numpy()])
    prediction_prob = np.vstack([prediction_prob, tf.nn.softmax(model.predict(x))])
```

However, if I get the prediction from model.predict(test_ds), somehow the order the prediction is different from the original dataset, so that it does not match with the original label. I am not sure if this is the 'bug' in tensorflow, or there is other explanation to this.

Also I cannot get the micro-averaging (though this is not that important for my goal)

```
fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(correct.ravel(), prediction_prob.ravel())
roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])
```

It gives the following error:

```
raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
ValueError: multiclass format is not supported
```